# Detectar evento de Touch de un SKSpriteNode Padre

Tags: swift2

Tengo un `btnPause` que es un `SKSpriteNode` y a éste nodo le agregó dos hijos:

```
let pauseOrange = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 12)
...
let pauseX = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "close")
...
btnPause.addChild(pauseOrange)
btnPause.addChild(pauseX)

self.addChild(btnPause)
```

Donde `btnPause` tiene el mismo tamaño y posición de su `pauseOrange` y `pauseX`.

Pero, con el nodo padre, no imprime nada en la función `touchesBegan`

```
if node == self.btnPause { print("btnPause")}
```

en cambio con su contenido si funciona en la función `touchesBegan`

```
if node == self.pauseOrange { print("pauseOrange")}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de que si yo toco el contenedor de los nodos, este (el contenedor) tome el evento en la función `touchesBegan`?

Lo que quiero lograr es que al presionar cualquier nodo hijo, es como si presionaran al nodo padre, así me ahorro de hacer muchos OR en la IF de la función `touchesBegan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución es crear un nodo transparente con del mismo tamaño del nodo padre, el cual debe estar sobre todas los nodos hijos, entonces si presionan ese nodo, significan que quisieron presionar el nodo padre o cualquier nodo hijo.